# JBOSS taking more than 100% CPU

Tags: java, memory, jboss

Even if no application is deployed on JBOSS 4.2.2, it is taking more than 100% CPU on my linux machine.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "more than 100% CPU"?

Comment: Maybe you would get better answers from serverfault.

Comment: 100% CPU means CPU usage are more than 100%

Comment: @grzegorz on multi-CPU machines running *nix, each CPU is often counted as 100%, so a fully loaded quad core machine would run at 400% CPU.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki: His CPU goes to 111.

Comment: OK. Fine. I got it. So it uses more than one thread, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a loop burning cpu cycles somewhere.

If you use Oracle Java 6 then attach with JVisualVM in the JDK to the running process, and run the CPU profiler to find out where the loop is.  You probably configured something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with the way that you have installed JBoss.  Look at the JBoss log files.